# Build gui in java desktop application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm developing a java-database desktop application using netbeans and swing. The application has so many features that creating gui has become a problem and it has a very old look when compared to other modern applications. I found javafx, swingx, jgoodies, netbeans platform and so on...and the discussion on these topics is never ending!! I need good support for customising tables,trees, toolbars and skins. what should i use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest you to go for javaFX. I had earlier worked on swing but now moved to javaFX.Benefits are

- Good look and feel
- can be used server side also.

Comment: Swing has a lot of Laf's

Comment: @alex2410 can swing be used as server side?

Comment: i think no, but i mean only about LaF's.

Comment: Is jre enough to run javafx? is it cross platform?

Comment: @Roronoa you need jdk-7u25.Java 8 also supports but its in beta so I would suggest you to go for java7

Answer (score 1):

Use the simplest method possible. Seriously, whatever you find easier go with. <strike>I find Eclipse Windows Builder is better than Netbeans but if installing the Eclipse plugin.</strike> Netbeans is probably a lot simpler than Eclipse Window Builder, but some people like me prefer Window Builder. Go with whatever you find easiest.

GUI building is complex in Java, they designed it well so it is hard as a novice to jump in, and it is better to start running then learn as you need more complex features. Google then becomes a good ally.